# Problem Powering 13.3 inch LCD Screen with 3.7v Battery

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, lcd, amperage, lipo

I have been working on a project that involves running a 13.3 inch lcd screen off of a rechargeable battery. I bought the lcd screen and controller board listed below and verified that it was working by plugging it into a working 12v 3a power supply. The specs of the screen specify that the screen requires 5-12v and more than 2a to function.

After verifying that the screen worked I tried hooking it up to my 3.7v lipo battery that you can also find listed below. I put the current through a voltage booster to get the voltage to 12v as required by the lcd screen. When I try the power the screen from the battery with the voltage booster it does not work correctly. The controller board powers on, then the screen flashes on, and then it shuts off and that process repeats. At first, I believed that this was because I was not supplying enough amperage to the lcd screen. I measured the amperage the screen was using when hooked up the the correct 12v 3a power supply and running. It was only using about 0.6a. The 4000mAh battery I have should easily be able to supply this amperage, therefore I do not believe a lack of amperage is the problem.

At this point I have no idea why I am unable to power the screen from my battery. After putting the current through the voltage booster it is giving 12v power and should be able to supply enough amperage for the screen. Is there anything else that I am missing? Or is there something else that could cause me not to be able to power the screen?

I am willing to go into futher detail or answer any questions to clarify. I apologize for being unclear, for I am new to electrical engineering and have little experience.

Thank you for your help!

Links:
LCD Screen: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XWVLNMT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWVLNMT)

LiPo Battery: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07BTTQDJQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BTTQDJQ)

Voltage Booster: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XWSV89D/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWSV89D)

Comment: It's usually a bad sign if the only links you have to your devices are amazon links. Do you have datasheets?

Comment: Building a power source like this yourself is probably a bad idea.  Your booster's output may be noisy or unstable, or the screen may have occasional peak loads especially on startup

Comment: Did you measure the battery voltage or at least the voltage at booster input when everything is connected? The system would be pulling 2A from the battery.

Answer (score 1):

The screen spec says "Input Power Adapter: 5Vdc-12Vdc More than 2A" - which I presume means that it may draw *up to* 2A. The XL6009 boost converter is rated for a maximum switching current of 4A. The 4000mAh Lipo cell has no current spec, but it can probably do 0.5C (2A), and the 2mm JST PH connector on it is rated for 2A.

So it should all be good, right? Not quite.

Watts = Volts x Amps. Your screen needs up to 2A at 12V, which is 24W. 24W/3.7V = **6.5A**. In practice the booster might only be 80% efficient, so the battery current might need to be 25% higher again, ie. ~8A. That's way more than the battery and booster can handle, so your setup does not come close to meeting the specified power input for your screen.

However you found that it actually only draws 0.6A after starting up. So lets do the calculations again. 12V x 0.6A = 7.2W. 7.2W/80% = 9W input power. 9W/3.7V = 2.4A. The booster should be able to handle 2.4A, but the battery connector (and wiring?) won't. So even if the screen never drew more than 0.6A your battery would still be overloaded.

You need a better battery, and perhaps a more powerful booster. One solution might be to get an extra cell and wire it in series to make make a 2S (7.4V) battery. This would halve the battery current, and *might* be enough to run your screen properly if it never drew more than 1A. The 2S battery would also last twice as long per charge, but would need an appropriate charger.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I think I will try to get a more powerful battery, around 10000mAh, along with possibly a more powerful booster. I will try this out and let you know if this solves my solution. Thank you again!